# phone inappbrowser doesn't start from full-zoomed-out when it loads huge image

Tags: image, cordova, zooming, inappbrowser

I have a window.open code to launch inappbrowser on phonegap. I use it for displaying image.
This inappbrowser has EnableViewPortScale=yes, so it's totally zoomable.

However, it seems like there is zoom-out-limit in inappbrowser. Here is the code.

```
window.open(myFullImageUrl, '_blank',  
    'location=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes,presentationstyle=pagesheet');
```

It's already zoomed-in a little. I can zoom-in-and-out because of EnableViewPortScale=yes for sure.

However, it seems like there is zoom-out-limit.
when i load up 1024x768 photo, it doesn't show fully zoomed-out photo(on both iOS and Android), but it's like 120%-ish already zoomed in.

I Just created stackoverflow account, so i can't upload photo. sorry!(it says i need 10 reputations to upload image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no true solution for this issue.
So what I did is I just continue using inAppBrowser, but just instead of directly loading image from Amazon server(that's where I stored all images), I just made my window.open to go to another my URL and attach that url as a parameter after '?'.

The reason why I did this is because then I can force the Image web-view to have brief Javascript and CSS to render this dang-image correctly.

And as you guys know, this page must have meta-data that allows user-scale true, and must NOT have max-scale value.

So, Yep. Long story short, If you DIRECTLY load up the image in the inAppBrowser of phonegap, there is NO WAY you can force the image to start with 'not even slightly zoomed-in, but perfectly zoomed-out to the max'. Your own Page, Your own JS and CSS is the way to go guys.